# C and Fortran interoperability for strings

Tags: c, arrays, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to call some Fortran code from C but I didn't find the proper way of passing a C char array.

```
   SUBROUTINE My_F_Code (c_message)  BIND(C, NAME='my_f_code')
     USE ISO_C_BINDING
     IMPLICIT NONE
     CHARACTER*(C_CHAR)      c_message
     CHARACTER*(256)         f_message
     CALL C_F_POINTER( C_LOC(c_message), f_message)
     WRITE(*,*) f_message,LEN(f_message)
   END
```

The `BIND(C)` force the parameter c_message to be size 1. How can I access to other elements of the c_message string?

Compiler : GCC 4.8.2

Comment: I'm confused.  Fortran 77 (and Fortran 90) does not have the F2K C interop feature.  In what way is your code Fortran 77?

Comment: I am confused as well. Gfortran compiles the code as Fortran 2008 and the `bind(C)` interface is Fortran 2003.

Comment: You must show the subroutine you are interfacing and the error messages you are getting. It is very important.

Comment: For example, `CHARACTER*(C_CHAR)` is not syntactically correct. You should just use `CHARACTER(kind=C_CHAR)` and don't care about if your code is F77 or F whatever else. Most Fortran 77 codes are valid Fortran 2008 codes.

Comment: You right, gfortran was using f2008 standard and doesn't have ISO_C_BINDING with f95 standard

Comment: So, can we really mix C and Fortran 77 without ISO_C_BINDING ?

Comment: I largely agree with what people are saying, but to respond to @VladimirF: `CHARACTER*(C_CHAR)` is valid.  It just doesn't mean what you (asker) think: it's a character of length `c_char`, not of kind `c_char`.  Unless `c_char` is `1` that isn't (F2008) C-interoperable.

Comment: You can mix them, just not portably , but it is not a clever thing to do. Just create a Fortran 2008 interface to the old code, unless you have to support some old legacy system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to call some Fortran77 code from C but I didn't find the proper way of passing a C char array.

All Fortran 77 implementations I've ever used have afforded implementation-specific mechanisms for interoperation with C.  Generally these involve the C side knowing the name-mangling and argument-passing conventions employed by the Fortran compiler, and using them at the interface.  The GCC system's conventions are not that hard to use.

You seem to be interested in the Fortran/C interop facility introduced in Fortran 2003, however.  Supposing that your Fortran 77 code also conforms with Fortran 2003 (or can be made to do so), it should be possible to write an interoperable wrapper in Fortran 2003.  Be aware, however, that the C interop facility does not provide (directly) for interoperability of Fortran variables or subprogram parameters of type `character` with length greater than 1 or kind different from `c_char`.  On the other hand, keep also in mind that the *length* of a Fortran character object is not the same thing as the *dimension(s)* of a character array.

You have a couple of interoperable alternatives for providing a C-facing interface by which to accept a C `char` array.  Perhaps the clearest one would be to accept a Fortran assumed-size `character` array:

```
SUBROUTINE My_F_Code (c_message)  BIND(C, NAME='my_f_code')
    USE ISO_C_BINDING
    IMPLICIT NONE
    CHARACTER(kind=C_CHAR), dimension(*), intent(in) :: c_message
    ! ...
END
```

The most likely alternative is to accept C's array pointer directly:

```
SUBROUTINE My_F_Code (c_message)  BIND(C, NAME='my_f_code')
    USE ISO_C_BINDING
    IMPLICIT NONE
    type(C_PTR), value :: c_message
    ! ...
END
```

The latter is necessary if the C-side array pointer might be null.  Both require an explicit length to be passed as well if the array cannot be relied upon to be null terminated.

In any event, if you ultimately want a Fortran `character` variable having length greater than 1 (as opposed to an array having dimension greater than 1), then the *interoperable* interfaces can't provide that directly -- such types are not among those to which the C interop provisions are applicable.  Unless you can rely on the default character kind to be `c_char`, you'll need to couple them with copy-in(/ copy-out) in order to convert the characters between kinds.  With the former interface, it should be obvious how you could copy the array to a Fortran scalar `character` having length greater than 1.  For the pointer variant, it might be useful to use a conversion function something like this:

```
subroutine C_string_ptr_to_F_string(C_string, F_string)
    use ISO_C_BINDING
    type(C_PTR), intent(in) :: C_string
    character(len=*), intent(out) :: F_string
    character(len=1, kind=C_CHAR), dimension(:), pointer :: p_chars
    integer :: i
    if (.not. C_associated(C_string)) then
      F_string = ' '
    else
      call C_F_pointer(C_string, p_chars, [huge(0)])
      do i = 1, len(F_string)
        if (p_chars(i) == C_NULL_CHAR) exit
        F_string(i:i) = p_chars(i)
      end do
      if (i <= len(F_string)) F_string(i:) = ' '
    end if
end subroutine
```

(Derived from the Fortran Wiki's [C_interface_module](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/c_interface_module)'s `C_F_string_ptr` subroutine)

On the other hand, if you can (or anyway *do*) rely on the default character kind to be `c_char` then you have an additional alternative.  You can usefully cause a character array such as the parameter in the first example to be associated with a scalar character object of default kind and length greater than one.  In particular, if a dummy argument of the wrapped function is a scalar character with assumed length, or with fixed length not exceeding the number of array elements, then you can rely on argument association to associate it with the character array in the wrapper.  In other words, in that case you can just pass the array as the actual argument.

Comment: With respect to the last paragraph, a copy is only required if kind conversion is needed.  A deferred length pointer of C_CHAR kind can be associated with the same storage sequence that is occupied by the C string, if need be.  From a brief inspection, the wiki page does not use deferred length character, presumably because gfortran support was lacking at the time it was written.

Comment: @IanH, thanks for the observation.  I have amended and extended my comments to discuss associating instead of copying, which indeed is to be preferred where it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
  SUBROUTINE FCODE(STR, N)
  CHARACTER*(*) STR
  INTEGER N
  WRITE(*,*), STR, N
  END


  void foo(char *str)
  {
      int N = 10;
      printf("Calling fortran\n");
      fcode_(str,  &N, strlen(str)); 
  }
```

You need to pass sgtring length as a hidden parameter.
    See my article here
   http://www.malcolmmclean.site11.com/www/MpiTutorial/CandFortran77.html

Comment: The given code assumes that the Fortran compiler decorates its symbols in a particular way (lower case, trailing underscore).  That convention is far from ubiquitous.  Conventions for the hidden character length may vary too.

Comment: They do vary indeed. The patch to change it from int to size_t in gfortran is already on the table. I assume a HUGE influx of clueless askers that used code like this.