# Passing strings to Fortran subroutine using ctypes

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes

I am currently trying to pass a string to a Fortran library. I have gotten other functions from this library to work, but this particular one seems to be unique in that it wants a string passed to it as an argument to the function.

Looking at the source code, the function requires three arguments

```
SUBROUTINE EZVOLLIB(VOLEQI,DBHOB,HTTOT,VOL)
```

and the arguments are defined:

```
  IMPLICIT NONE

  CHARACTER*(*)   VOLEQI
  CHARACTER*10 VOLEQ
  REAL DBHOB,HTTOT,TOPD, VOL(15), MHT
  INTEGER REGN,ERRFLG
```

In Python my call to the function looks like

```
from ctypes import *

mylib = cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/bryce/Programming/opencompile/libvollib.so')

dbhob = c_float(42.2)
vol = (c_float * 15)()
voleqi = c_char_p("101DVEW119 ")

mylib.ezvollib_(voleqi, dbhob, vol)
```

This runs without a segmentation fault, but does not seem to "fill" the variable `vol` with the desired 15 float values.

Is there any way to get `vol` to retrieve the values being returned from the `EZVOLLIB` function?

Comment: What 15 float values?

Comment: *the function requires three arguments* ... `EZVOLLIB(VOLEQI,DBHOB,HTTOT,VOL)` ??

Answer (score 0):

There are many similar questions here, but it is hard to find an *exact* duplicate. There are several possible ways to do that with different degrees of universal correctness and portability.

The most correct way is to use modern Fortran to C interoperability as explained in [fortran77, iso_c_binding and c string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247242/fortran77-iso-c-binding-and-c-string)  That requires writing more Fortran wrapping code.

There are people who are strictly against writing any more Fortran, even-though that is the only portable solution. In that case they must explore what is the actual calling convention for Fortran strings in their compiler. Usually a hidden integer argument with the string length is passed to the subroutine. For gfortran see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Argument-passing-conventions.html

Your `ctypes` interface could employ these compiler-specific calling conventions but then the interface will be, well, compiler-specific. But you are already relying on the specific name mangling `ezvollib_` and that is compiler-specific as well. You can find examples here on SO where people were bitten by relying on that.

Also note, as noted by High Performance Mark, that the subroutine in question has four arguments, not three: `EZVOLLIB(VOLEQI,DBHOB,HTTOT,VOL)`. Calling it with just three as in `mylib.ezvollib_(voleqi, dbhob, vol)` is an error. You are missing the `HTTOT` argument.